# It wont conncect from Ionic to my remote Database

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic4, pouchdb

I created a database on Fauxten and I am trying now to connect it to my project. I can open the link on my browser but when I try to call it in the app nothing happens. I can't see where I miss something

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {
  private db;
  url = 'http://localhost:5984/_utils/#database/grundbaustein/_all_docs';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  setUpPDB() {
    this.db = new PouchDB(this.url);
  }

  getdataDB() {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });

    }

  }
```

that the Service I want to use to get access to my Database

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage  {

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

ionViewDidLoad() {
this.api.setUpPDB();
this.api.getdataDB();

  }
}
```

And thats my Page.ts where I wanna use the information I get from the database.

```
{
  "name": "firstapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.17.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@types/pouchdb": "^6.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "pouchdb": "^7.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling getdataDB in ionViewDidLoad you're just calling setUpPDB. Hence the method isn't called and the get request isn't made

**Update**

ngOnInit won't work the same way ionViewDidLoad does cuz it only works once when the component is created and not every time you nav to an ionic page. But try this to see if you're getting to this component

Try this and let me know what happens:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.setUpPDB();
    this.api.getdataDB();

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that mistake but still it doesn't show anything in my console @fchoura

Comment: Did you try to add a log/breakpoint in getdataDB before the http call? Just to check if you're calling that method or not (maybe for some reason it's not getting to that point)

Comment: could you suggest me how to do that? @fchoura

Comment: Just add a console.log("Im in getDatadb") before you do this.http.get() and check if you get a log message

Comment: Okay so you have something wrong that I cant see in the code you provided. The main issue is that your code is not getting to ionViewDidLoad hence your call is not running and that's why you can't see anything log on your dev tools console

Comment: I replaced the ionViewDidLoad with an Button and now I get the Error msg: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Error reading @fchoura

Comment: Check my update if that doesn't work then you've got something wrong with your setup

Comment: sadly same error msg. I just saw that in terminal I get [info] POST /wsman 404 - 127.0.0.1 and before it worked totally fine @fchoura

Comment: I can't help more with the code you provided.If the project is not huge and you're just testing stuff out/learning I'd recommend start another one and pay attention to the flow of the application

Comment: That's weird. anyway thanks for taking your time to help me! @fchoura